# JsStore or IndexedDB missing data

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

We're pretty deep into a PWA with around 30 tables in IndexedDB. We're using JsStore as our data access for all CRUD operations.

Intermittently, an entire data table will lose its data. No records, no errors, just gone. This is incredible difficult to debug. It seems to be happening when we update a record or group of records on the same table. Some of these tables have around 80+ properties.

We did add using navigator storage at app launch, however the problem still persists.

```
        if (navigator.storage && navigator.storage.persist) {
            const isPersisted = await navigator.storage.persisted()
            console.log(`Persisted storage granted: ${isPersisted}`)
            const isPersist = await navigator.storage.persist()
            console.log(`Persisted storage granted: ${isPersist}`)
        }]
```

We are not using the JsStore's transactional API. Any hints or guidance will be helpful.

We have noticed similar issues posted on the web around IndexedDB in general losing data.

Thanks in advance.